# libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: rhel, libraries, openssl, shared-library, node.js

When attempting to run Cloud9 IDE locally after its installation I receive this error:

```
# bin/cloud9.sh
Linux 64 bit
support/node-builds-v4/node-linux64: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It looks strange, because the library is in `/lib`, `/usr/lib` and other locations through symbolic links.

For check, here is the main file:

```
# ls -l /usr/lib | grep libssl
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 root root   319816 Oct  6  2014 libssl.so.0.9.8
```

Why does it not find the file, does it need to be included in any other `$PATH` variable or what can be the cause?

**Updates:**

It seems to be a wider problem with ssl:

```
# git submodule update --init --recursive
Cloning into 'support/sass'...
fatal: remote error:
  Repository not found.
Clone of 'git://github.com/visionmedia/sass.js.git' into submodule path 'support/sass' failed
Failed to recurse into submodule path 'support/connect'
```

The failed module needs `ssl` to download, while the others that downloaded don't:

```
# cat .gitmodules
[submodule "support/socket.io-client"]
    path = support/socket.io-client
    url = http://github.com/ajaxorg/socket.io-client.git
[submodule "support/uglify-js"]
    path = support/uglify-js
    url = http://github.com/ajaxorg/UglifyJS.git
[submodule "support/connect"]
    path = support/connect
    url = https://github.com/ajaxorg/connect.git
```

Check openssl version:

```
# yum list installed openssl
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security, ulninfo
Installed Packages
openssl.x86_64                      1.0.1e-42.el6
```

64 bit installed `openssl` libraries:

```
# ls -l /usr/lib64 | grep libssl
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   261248 Nov  4 10:37 libssl3.so
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       16 Dec  1 10:30 libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.0.1e
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   324680 Jun  5  2014 libssl.so.0.9.8e
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       16 Dec  1 10:29 libssl.so.10 -> libssl.so.1.0.1e
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   444184 Jul 23 09:43 libssl.so.1.0.1e
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       16 Dec  3 11:29 libssl.so.6 -> libssl.so.0.9.8e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see by searching for an RPM with [libssl.so.0.9.8](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libssl.so.0.9.8), this is an old file, and unlikely to be part of the RPM which you listed for openssl.  You can *see* what files are part of the RPM using

```
rpm -ql openssl.x86_64
```

and further, you can see what RPM that file might belong to by

```
rpm -qf /usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8
```

and also what *architecture* the file uses by

```
file /usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8
```

The most likely explanation is (one or more of):

- the file was copied from some other machine
- it is a 32-bit library
- the [`ldconfig`](http://www.skrenta.com/rt/man/ldconfig.8.html) path for 64-bit libraries uses `/usr/lib64` (not `/usr/lib`).

A 64-bit application cannot load a 32-bit shared library, and will only find its libraries where `ldconfig` says it may.

Comment: Excellent, then I'm thinking about just dynamically linking the new SSL library into the location of the old file (`libssl.so.0.9.8`)

Comment: That might work (openssl seems to rarely break forward-compatibility).

Comment: The setup worked with the `ln -fs /usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8e /usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8`